# Estimate the performance impact of increasing certificate key size for requests signing

Tags: java, performance, certificate, weblogic, digital-signature

I'm interested in how to estimate the performance impact of increasing the RSA key size in the certificates that are used for signing the requests to the server.

We do have a an Oracle WebLogic Application server running an Java application that is processing SOAP requests.
We use a self created root certificate to create client certificates.
The clients use this client certificates to sign their request that are checked for a valid signature.

How could I reasonable estimate a performance impact when changing the size of the key in the client certificate?

I consider that for this is needed to know:

- size of the increase of key width (e.g.: from 1024bit to 3072bit)
- current amount of requests per hour/minute
- current size of signed requests on average (in kb/mb)

Is there a way of estimating the impact?